# Android .Wav E/WVMExtractor( 40): Failed to open libwvm.so

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have the following code...

```
public class GL2JNIActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
...
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    mView = new GL2JNIView(getApplication());
    mView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    lib.setContext(this);
    lib.setSoundPool(new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0));
    lib.getSoundPool().setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                int status) {
            lib.setLoaded(true);
        }
    });
    lib.setSoundID(lib.getSoundPool().load(this, R.raw.a, 1));
    lib.setAudioManager((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE));
    setContentView(mView);
}
```

Then I call it using a JNI callback in a different class...

```
public class GL2JNILib {
    ...
    public void playA() {
    //setSoundID(getSoundPool().load(context, R.raw.a, 1));
    float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
    // Is the sound loaded already?
    if (loaded) {
        soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
        Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
    }
}
```

}

I however would like to comment the line in onCreate and uncomment the one in the lib (so I can change the note). But when I do this I see the following error....

> E/WVMExtractor(   40): Failed to open libwvm.so

It doesn't crash or anything, just doesn't play the sound. Any ideas?

Comment: I set all the values in the activity (and did a switch on ID) but this seems drastic.

Comment: lib widevine i.e. drm error?

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance testing on a Samsung device? It's known that they did not include some libraries or personalized them for releases < 5.0.